# Selfie segmentation using image processing techniques

Tags: java, android, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I want to perform selfie segmentation on Android, similar to what Zoom does. However, I would like to do it preferrably without using deep learning models and instead rely solely on conventional image processing and computer vision techniques, such as using only OpenCV or just Android SDK. Google [MLKit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/selfie-segmentation) or Mediapipe have this functionalities but I don't want to include a large library to do so, so that library size is my only concern. My goal is to achieve fast selfie segmentation; may not be very accurate but it's fine as long as it's not a large library.

How can I do that? I assume apps like Zoom were probably using image processing techniques before using deep learning models, so there should be ways to achieve that.

[image]

I did some simple experiments using OpenCV's `grabcut` in Python. But it's slow yet it wasn't accurate at all.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv.imread('selfie.jpg')
assert img is not None, "file could not be read, check with os.path.exists()"
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)
bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
rect = (0,0,530,710)
cv.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]
plt.imshow(img),plt.colorbar(),plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Honestly this feels a bit broad since if you search on "opencv image segmentation" brings up a few algorithms. Which algorithms were the most successful or accurate depends on the definition of "success" or "accurate". Also realize that Zoom for Android has a minimum hardware requirement for background blur/virtual background: https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360043484511

Comment: My only concern is to avoid large libraries and preferrably use lightweight solutions like OpenCV or what is available natively in Android.

Comment: If you look at attempts at packing an OpenCV into Android I'm not sure if there is much space savings as the older OpenCV Manager (a separate app) was deprecated a long time ago, and the Play Store currently breaks up app delivery by ABI architecture. Also in your code you don't use the same input image sizes as ML solutions, https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/image_segmenter#selfie-model

Comment: Yeah I agree. Maybe I should stick to deep models. But yet I have to import TFLite library which still is an overhead. But maybe that's smaller than MLKit or MediaPipe libraries. I think that's minimum I have to include anyways. Right? Any thoughts?

Comment: TFLite is what both MLKit and MediaPipe use under the hood. The beta status of both higher SDKs may be issues of device compatibility, so any problem that either higher level framework 'fixes' is something that needs to be done in the lower layer by you without them. Given how long image segmentation has been 'beta' it is unclear when it will leave such status. TLDR: pick one that fits best for you but under the hood MLKit & MediaPipe both use the same image segment binaries, look at 'model card' for details.

Comment: Hmm I didn't know both use the same .tflite model! But I think at least including a TFLite library is less size than including MLKit or Mediapipe itself. Plus, it gives higher flexibility to add more Deep Learning features later. I wish there were some examples how to use this TFLite model using the camera app.

Comment: If the foreground (person) and background are distinct, then simple thresholding should work with some morphology to clean it up. However, if they are not distinct, then I suspect you will need AI/Deep Learning to do that. You might also be able to do that with the help of depth information available on many cellphones. Threshold the depth information

Comment: @fmw42 interesting. Can you share some sample code for your morphology approach?

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/selfie-segmentation-using-opencv/14699

Answer (score 1):

You asked for an example of thresholding and morphology in Python/OpenCV. In the following, I show that plus a better method that simply thresholds and gets the largest contour. The latter method should not be as image and threshold dependent.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('headshot.png')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# threshold on background
lower = (160,160,160)
upper = (255,255,255)
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# invert
thresh = 255 - thresh

# pad
thresh2 = cv2.copyMakeBorder(thresh, 20, 20, 20, 20, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(0,0,0))

# apply morphology open and close to clean up (kernel will be image and threshold dependent)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (15,15))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh2, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# invert
morph = 255 - morph

# crop to remove pad
result1 = morph[20:hh+20, 20:ww+20]

# BETTER should be to just get the largest contour from the threshold image
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw black filled contour on white background as mas
result2 = np.full_like(thresh, 255)
cv2.drawContours(result2, [big_contour], 0, 0, -1)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('headshot_thresh.png', thresh2)
cv2.imwrite('headshot_morph.png', morph)
cv2.imwrite('headshot_result1.png', result1)
cv2.imwrite('headshot_result2.png', result2)

# show results
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh2)
cv2.imshow('morph', morph)
cv2.imshow('result1', result1)
cv2.imshow('result2', result2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Result from threshold and morphology:

[image]

Result from threshold and use largest contour:

[image]

Comment: But will it work on any selfies? I want to run it on camera. Looks like there are many threshold values that we need to set manually.

Comment: As I said above "If the foreground (person) and background are distinct, then simple thresholding should work with some morphology to clean it up. However, if they are not distinct, then I suspect you will need AI/Deep Learning to do that. You might also be able to do that with the help of depth information available on many cellphones. Threshold the depth information".  So this method will not work on all selfies, since the background will not always be distinct from the foreground.